# How can get numbers between brackets ([ ]) in a string

Tags: java

I have a string like it:

`String msg = "[05] [06] [07] [08] [09] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15] [16]";`

And I need to get the numbers between the brakets in an array. Can Anyone help me?

Comment: In particular, think about reducing the problem: you first need to get "the bits in brackets" and then parse each one (assuming you want `int` values).

Comment: For the 1st step (isolate parts of the string), you should have a look at some methods of the `String` class, in particular `split()`

Answer (score 4):

Pseudo code:

```
String replace '[' with ''
String replace ']' with ''
String split at ' '
```

Comment: That pseudo code is only some characters away from real code :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple regular expression to find all numbers:

```
String msg = "[05] [06] [07] [08] [09] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15] [16]";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+").matcher(msg);
while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

If it's important to parse only the numbers **between the brackets**, and not all numbers in the string, then you can use this variant:

```
String msg = "[05] [06] [07] [08] [09] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15] [16]";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[([0-9]+)\\]").matcher(msg);
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

In both cases, the output is the same:

```
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
```

Comment: This regex won't get just the numbers between the brackets (it will get any, be careful OP).

Comment: @jsn if the rest of the input is the same as the example string, then it doesn't matter. But you're right, I've added a variant of the original code to the answer, in case the brackets are important.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use String Tokenizer as:

```
String msg = "[05] [06] [07] [08] [09] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15] [16]";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(msg, "[,], ");

while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
     System.out.println("Token: "+ st.nextToken());
}
```

output:

```
Token: 05
Token: 06
Token: 07
Token: 08
Token: 09
Token: 10
Token: 11
Token: 12
Token: 13
Token: 14
Token: 15
Token: 16
```